# docker-compose add a hostname to a service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a backuppc local service running e.g. 127.0.0.1:8081 .
I can also reach it directly on http://172.23.0.4 (container ip)

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  backuppc-app:
    image: tiredofit/backuppc
    container_name: backuppc-app
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
      - "8082:10050"
    environment:
      - BACKUPPC_UUID=1000
      - BACKUPPC_GUID=1000
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backuppc-mysql
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy
```

I want to assign it a hostname, something like

```yaml
    hostname: backup.local
```

I tried to add it but doesn't work as expected

```yaml
      backuppc-app:
        image: tiredofit/backuppc
        container_name: backuppc-app
        hostname: backup.local
```

Should I manually edit my local /ets/hosts ?

```
    172.23.0.4    backup.local
```

Comment: "doesn't work as expected" is not a problem description. What exactly happens? Why exactly is that wrong?

Comment: 502 Bad Gateway
openresty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hostname as a network alias:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  backuppc-app:
    networks:
      nginx-proxy:
        aliases:
        - backup.local
```

For containers in `nginx-proxy` network it will be available both as `backuppc-app` and as `backup.local`.

If you want that hostname to be visible to your host you need to modify hosts file. But don't put container IP there - it can change. Rather add it as another name for localhost:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost myhostname backup.local
```

Then you can access it both with `localhost:8081` and `backup.local:8081` (that works due to port forwarding you've declared with `ports:` key).